# Docker Swarm: How to Sniff Network Traffic

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, packet-sniffers

I would like to sniff the traffic of a running container on a Docker Swarm on an overlay network without stopping or interfering with the container. Is there a simple way to do it?

At the moment the only solution I have is by sniffing the traffic network on the node (using tcpdump in a container with `--net host`) but I want something more generic that doesn't need `--privileged` to run.

Comment: Hi! Have you found a way for doing this? I'm also curious whether a whole docker network can be sniffed without specifying containers....

Comment: I think a colleague did it in the end. I will ask him

Comment: Hi, as @Cecile said I wrote some time ago a tool that would automate the traffic network sniffing and dump the network packets into pcap files in an organized manner. You can check it out here: https://github.com/fr0gs/docker-watcher, I didn't try it in an overlay network though.